# How to Stub Responses with ruby Aws::Lambda::Client SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-lambda, mocking, aws-sdk

How do you mock lambda responses using the AWS ruby SDK ?

The documentation provided only gives basic usage examples for S3, which are not relevant for lambda requests.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the code of `stub_responses`, it brings you to `convert_stub`. There seems to be three viable options to mock the responses with: `Proc`, `Hash`and the `else` statement.

```
def convert_stub(operation_name, stub)
  case stub
  when Proc then stub
  when Exception, Class then { error: stub }
  when String then service_error_stub(stub)
  when Hash then http_response_stub(operation_name, stub)
  else { data: stub }
  end
end
```

[source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/5e1a4cb8bad558cdfb3bef86a4714c47f7e4bf03/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/client_stubs.rb#L261)

In the mocking examples below, I have my AWS client setup as such.

```
aws_credentials = {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_key,
    secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret,
    stub_responses: Rails.env.test?
}
LAMBDA_CLIENT = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(aws_credentials)
```

---

**Mocking Aws::Lambda::Types::InvocationResponse**

The `else` statement allows you to essentially return the same object back. So the best way to mock the response, is to utilize the same class that is being used outside of the test environment. `Aws::Lambda::Types::InvocationResponse`

```
context do
  before do
    LAMBDA_CLIENT.stub_responses(
        :invoke,
        Aws::Lambda::Types::InvocationResponse.new(
            executed_version: "$LATEST",
            function_error: nil,
            log_result: nil,
            payload: StringIO.new("hello".to_json),
            status_code: 200
        )
    )
  end
  it { ... }
end
```

---

**Mocking the HTTP Response**

Following the logic of using a `Hash`, we need to peak into what `http_response_stub` does.

```
def http_response_stub(operation_name, data)
  if Hash === data && data.keys.sort == [:body, :headers, :status_code]
    { http: hash_to_http_resp(data) }
  else
    { http: data_to_http_resp(operation_name, data) }
  end
end
```

[source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/5e1a4cb8bad558cdfb3bef86a4714c47f7e4bf03/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/client_stubs.rb#L275)

Evidently they are looking for a `Hash` with the following keys `[:body, :headers, :status_code]`

```
context do
  before do
    LAMBDA_CLIENT.stub_responses(
        :invoke,
        {
            body: {testing: true}.to_json,
            headers: {},
            status_code: 200
        }
    )
  end

  it { ... }
end
```